# Twig not working in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, twig, yii2-advanced-app, yii-extensions

I want to use **Twig** in **Yii2 framework** but it isn't working.

I am using [yii2-app-advanced](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced) as the base project but I am new in the Yii world so I think I am not configuring Twig in the right way.

First I downloaded it using:

```
composer require yiisoft/yii2-twig
```

Then I follow this instructions but it's not easy to understand: 
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-twig/blob/HEAD/docs/guide/installation.md#configuring-application

It says:
**In order to start using Twig you need to configure view component like the following:**

```
[
    'components' => [
        'view' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\View',
            'renderers' => [
                'twig' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\twig\ViewRenderer',
                    'cachePath' => '@runtime/Twig/cache',
                    // Array of twig options:
                    'options' => [
                        'auto_reload' => true,
                    ],
                    'globals' => [
                        'html' => ['class' => '\yii\helpers\Html'],
                    ],
                    'uses' => ['yii\bootstrap'],
                ],
                // ...
            ],
        ],
    ],
]
```

**In which file I have to paste this code?**

---

In my index.php file I added the following code but it is not working:

```
{% if true %}
    <p>It is true.</p>
{% else %}
    <p>It is false.</p>        
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it doing this:

I modified the file backend/config/main-local-php:

```
<?php

$config = [
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'CPeTotdTU98geIyM7q0PljmCpJbupPN4',
        ],
        'view' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\View',
            'renderers' => [
                'twig' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\twig\ViewRenderer',
                    'cachePath' => '@runtime/Twig/cache',
                    // Array of twig options:
                    'options' => [
                        'auto_reload' => true,
                    ],
                    'globals' => [
                        'html' => ['class' => '\yii\helpers\Html'],
                    ],
                    'uses' => ['yii\bootstrap'],
                ],
                // ...
            ],
        ],
    ],
];

if (!YII_ENV_TEST) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
    ];

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
    ];
}

return $config;
```

The SiteController.php file has the actionIndex() function. I added the extension **.twig**:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    return $this->render('index.twig');
}
```

And then I modified the name of the file backend/views/sire/index.php to **index.twig**.